# can someone help me fix, my If else statement is not working

Tags: c#

I have the following code and I dont't know where did I do wrong, the goal is :when user type r or s or q
it will trigger the corresponding functions. However, it only work for the 1st letter

```
using System;


public class dice
{
int count = 0;
static void roll()
{
   Console.WriteLine("roll") ;
}
static void status() 
{
    Console.WriteLine("status") ;
}
public void Menu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a command(r - roll, s - status, q- quit):");
    if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("r"))
    {
        roll();
    }
    else if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("s"))
    {
        status();
    }
    else if (Console.ReadLine().Equals("q"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing");
    }
    }
    }
   class program
   {


   public static void Main()
   {


    dice player = new dice();
    player.Menu();
   }
   }
```

Comment: `public class dice()` -> `public class dice`

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive of the problem you're having or question you're asking. The title should be clear enough about the subject of your question that it has meaning to a future user of this site who is scanning a list of search results looking for a solution to their problem. Your current title provides nothing that would be useful to that future user. While you're making that edit, you can also make it more clear what the actual problem is that you're having. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean it executes only once and you need it to repeat? Then you need a loop, e.g. while, which will break when user types q.

Comment: You are potentially read the console input three times instead of once, messing up your whole `if`-`elseif` chain.

Comment: no, I mean when I type r it triggers roll function but when I type s or q it does nothing

Comment: You call your method menu() only once, you enter 1 letter and method exits.Main exits.It does just as its written to do.If you want to enter more letters you should create for ex. While loop

Comment: If you type anything other than r, it'll prompt them again for a new input.

Answer (score 6):

Do your read *once* and store the result in a variable :

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
```

then use the variable in your tests.

And use a loop, that's a usual handy way to do such console menu.

```
while(true) // The loop exits on "break" statement.
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a command(r - roll, s - status, q- quit):");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input == "r")
    {
        roll();
    }
    else if (input == "s")
    {
        status();
    }
    else if (input == "q")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I just applied and it work

Comment: @Yukitotech you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

I like [Pac0's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479251/pac0) solution but personally I would stick to `Console.ReadKey()` instead of `Console.ReadLine()` if you're only checking for single-character inputs.

This could look like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a command(r - roll, s - status, q- quit):");

var pressedKey = Console.ReadKey().Key;
if (pressedKey == ConsoleKey.R)
{
    roll();
}
else if (pressedKey == ConsoleKey.S)
{
    status();
}
else if (pressedKey == ConsoleKey.Q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing");
}
```

Comment: Definitely, I agree, I missed this part

Answer (score -1):

Think about a buffer where all user input is currently held. When you use Console.ReadLine(), it moves a char from the input and compare it to the first letter.
Then, when you use Console.ReadLine for the second time, it look the second input of the user, which is not exist.

```
char a = Console.ReadLine()
if(a=='s')
    do something
```

that is, put user input in another variable and compare to it.

Comment: This won't even compile.

Comment: thank you, now I understand my pb.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I focused more on explaining the problem rather then providing line of code. But I'll take it more seriously next time I give an answer

Comment: Still won't compile - `Console.ReadLine()` returns a `string`, not a `char`.